# Check if passwords are equal jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to validate whether two entered passwords are the same or not. But I can't seem to get it working. No matter what values I enter in my input fields, the result is always "true". Can you see what I am doing wrong?

HTML:

```
<div class="form-group" id="password">
<input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" name="password">
</div>
<div class="form-group" id="repassword">
<input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Confirm Password" name="repassword">
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
    //Check if password is set
    $('input[name=password]').blur(function() {
        if($(this).val().length == 0){
            $('#password').addClass('has-error');
        } else {
            $('#password').addClass('has-success');
        }
    });
    //Check if repassword is set
    $('input[name=repassword]').blur(function() {
        if($(this).val().length == 0){
            $('#repassword').addClass('has-error');
        } else {
            $('#repassword').addClass('has-success');
        }
    });
    //Check if password and repassword are equal
    $('input[name=password]').blur(function() {
        if ($(this).attr('value') !== $('input[name=repassword]').attr('value')) {
            $('#password').addClass('has-error');
            $('#repassword').addClass('has-error');
        } else {
            $('#password').addClass('has-success');
            $('#repassword').addClass('has-success');
        }
    });
```

Comment: Is there a reason that the actions are being bound separately?

Comment: You're using `val()` so you know it exists, yet for some reason you suddenly decided to use `attr('value')`, why ?

Comment: Please tell me you also have server code in place that also checks. Doing anything with passwords client side is scary.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should be using `.val()` to get the value of the textbox

**You could simplify the whole thing to this:**

```
$('input').blur(function() {
    var pass = $('input[name=password]').val();
    var repass = $('input[name=repassword]').val();
    if(($('input[name=password]').val().length == 0) || ($('input[name=repassword]').val().length == 0)){
        $('#password').addClass('has-error');
    }
    else if (pass != repass) {
        $('#password').addClass('has-error');
        $('#repassword').addClass('has-error');
    }
    else {
        $('#password').removeClass().addClass('has-success');
        $('#repassword').removeClass().addClass('has-success');
    }
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/6GmZX/2/)**

You could use `$('input').blur(function()` instead, that way it will trigger on all inputs

Comment: Thanks a lot. It was a inadvertent mistake not to specify the whole thing in once function.

Answer (score 6):

You're never removing any of the classes, you have to remove them to make it work, otherwise css specificity will only show the styles for the most specific class

It could all be written much simpler

```
$('input[name=password], input[name=repassword]').on('change', function () {
    var password   = $('input[name=password]'),
        repassword = $('input[name=repassword]'),
        both       = password.add(repassword).removeClass('has-success has-error');

    password.addClass(
        password.val().length > 0 ? 'has-success' : 'has-error' 
    );
    repassword.addClass(
        password.val().length > 0 ? 'has-success' : 'has-error'
    );

    if (password.val() != repassword.val()) {
        both.addClass('has-error');
    }
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/TFhT3/)

Comment: wow, I wasn't aware you could use `removeClass` to remove two classes - you wouldn't expect that based on the name. good, readable answer. (although the essence of the OP's error was the non-use of `val()`)

Answer (score 4):

Use `domElem.value` or `$(domElem).val()` to get the value of a `form` element:

[**WORKING JSFIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/fiddleyetu/L8jUF/1/)

```
$('input').on('input',function() {
    var pass = $('input[name=password]'),
        reps = $('input[name=repassword]'),
        pass_cont = $('#password'),
        reps_cont = $('#repassword');
     !$(this).is( '[name=password]' ) || $(function() {
         pass_cont.addClass( pass.val().length === 0 ? 'has-error' : 'has-success' )
         .removeClass( pass.val().length === 0 ? 'has-success' : 'has-error' );
     })();
     !$(this).is( '[name=repassword]' ) || $(function() {
         reps_cont.addClass( reps.val() === pass.val() ? 'has-success' : 'has-error' )
         .removeClass( reps.val() === pass.val() ? 'has-error' : 'has-success' );
     })();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

It should be `$(this).val()`, not `$(this).attr('value')`. And check both fields when either is blurred:

```
$('input').blur(function () {
    if ($('input[name=password]').val() != $('input[name=repassword]').val()) {
        $('#password').removeClass().addClass('has-error');
        $('#repassword').removeClass().addClass('has-error');
    } else {
        $('#password').removeClass().addClass('has-success');
        $('#repassword').removeClass().addClass('has-success');
    }
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/6GmZX/1)**

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what the others have said about using `val()` to get the value of the element instead of `attr('val')` (which could be derived from the HTML), the example also didn't work because:

- You need to remove the `has-error` and `has-success` class before adding one or the other
- You are checking the value of the second password field `onblur` of the first one. It seems like you should compare the two in one event handler as in adeneo's answer.

Answer (score 0):

A more general way, using classes and without re-finding jquery objects:

```
    $('.psw')               .on('keyup', checkPasses)
function checkPasses (e) {
    $ps1 = $(e.delegateTarget)
    $ps2 = $ps1.siblings('.psw')
    $pss = $ps1.add($ps2)
    if ( $ps1.val() == $ps2.val() ) {
        $pss.css('color', 'green')[0].setCustomValidity('')         
  } else {      
        $pss.css('color', 'red')[0].setCustomValidity('Passwords do not match')
    }
}
```